# doing a select count(col), max(col), column_name_data from table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i do a `select count(artc_id) as cval, max(srt_id) as maxval, artc_title from table where artc_pub = 1`

So I can get results like:

```
       cval | maxval | artc_title | artc_pub
    -----------------------------------------
       4         4     Title 1         1 
                       Title 2         1
                       Title 3         1
                       Title 4         1
```

Part of my table is below

```
artc_id | srt_id | artc_title | artc_pub
-----------------------------------------
   1         1     Title 1         1 
   2         2     Title 2         1
   3         3     Title 3         1
   4         4     Title 4         1
   1         5     Title 1         2
   2         6     Title 2         2
```

I tried `select count(artc_id) as cval, max(srt_id) as maxval, artc_title from table where artc_pub = 1` but this gives me only a single line with the first title. I guess there must be more than a plain old select here.

All the answers below give me results like this:

```
cval;maxval;artc_title
1   ;     1; Title 1
1   ;     2; Title 2
1   ;     3; Title 3
1   ;     4; Title 4
1   ;     5; Title 5
```

Not like how I mentioned up in my question.

Comment: Pls see the additions to my question. Group by does not seem to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `GROUP BY` here to group the results by the "article title":

```
SELECT
    COUNT(artc_id) AS cval,
    MAX(srt_id) AS maxval,
    artc_title
FROM
    table
WHERE
    artc_pub = 1
GROUP BY
    artc_title
ORDER BY
    artc_title;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's beter to have 2 queries, one for the aggregates and one for the titles:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cval, 
       MAX(srt_id) AS maxval
FROM table 
WHERE artc_pub = 1 ;

SELECT artc_title 
FROM table 
WHERE artc_pub = 1 ;
```

---

You could also use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to combine the titles in one row:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cval, 
       MAX(srt_id) AS maxval,
       GROUP_CONCAT(artc_title ORDER BY srt_id SEPARATOR ', ') 
           AS artc_title  
FROM table 
WHERE artc_pub = 1 ;
```

---

You could also combine these two with a join, but you'll have a lot of duplicate data returned:

```
SELECT ag . cval, 
       ag . maxval, 
       t  . artc_title 
FROM 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cval, 
             MAX(srt_id) AS maxval
      FROM table 
      WHERE artc_pub = 1 
    ) AS ag
  CROSS JOIN
    table AS t 
WHERE t.artc_pub = 1 ;
```

And if MySQL ever gets window functions (optimists read: when it will have), the above will be written:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER ()    AS cval, 
       MAX(srt_id) OVER () AS maxval, 
       artc_title 
FROM table 
WHERE artc_pub = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY artc_title` like so:

```
select 
  count(artc_id) as cval, 
  max(srt_id) as maxval, 
  artc_title 
from table 
where artc_pub = 1
GROUP BY artc_title
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing your grouping term

```
 SELECT count(artc_id) AS cval, max(srt_id) AS maxval, artc_title 
       FROM table
       WHERE artc_pub = 1
       GROUP BY artc_title
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried>>

```
select count(artc_id) as cval, max(srt_id) as maxval, artc_title from table where artc_pub = 1 Group By artc_title
```

I hope this will work.